# Nested taxonomies in views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm creating a site which has products, brands and affiliates. Products and brands are in the same taxonomy while affiliates are separate.

Products are terms that are children to brands. Affiliates are referenced in the brand term. I have the basic structure below for reference.

I'm trying to create a view that shows a users 10 favorite products along with the brand and url's for affiliates that carry the product. I've made my relationships in the view, but instead of displaying each brand with a link to the affiliates it duplicates the brand once per affiliate. In other words, if the brand has 3 affiliates it would show the brand 3 times with a single affiliate link under each.

How can I make my view combine the affiliates into a single result?

```
Product/brand taxonomy 
-name
-affiliate(term reference to affiliates)

Affiliates taxonomy
-name
-logo
-url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick fix you can make 'Distinct' in the view setting setting.